# AWS Glue check file contents correctness

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl, aws-glue

I have a project in AWS to insert data from some files, which will be in S3, to Redshift. The point is that the ETL has to be scheduled each day to find new files in S3 and then check if those files are correct. However, this has to be done with custom code as the files can have different formats depending of their kind, provider, etc. 
I see that AWS Glue allows to schedule, crawl and do the ETL. However I'm lost at how to one can create its own code for the ETL and parse the files to check the correctness before ending up doing the copy instruction from S3 to Redshift. Do you know if that can be done and how?

Another issue is that if the correctness is OK then, the system should upload the data from S3 to a web via some API. But if it's not the file should be left into an ftp email. Here again, do you know if that can be done as well with the AWS Glue and how?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write your glue/spark code, upload it to s3 and create a glue job referring to this script/library. Anything you want to write in python can be done in glue. its just a wrapper around spark which in turn uses python....

Comment: I have connected a Zeppelin notebook to a AWS Glue endpoint. I could run pyspark code and glue libraries code. However, I will need to use some python libraries. Only by importing the paramiko library with "import paramiko" I get the following error: 
Fail to execute line 5: import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-895507894114377331.py", line 380, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paramiko'. How to use python libraries in AWS Glue endpoints?

Comment: At the time of provisioning your endpoint you should add ur libraries in the python library path. Remember... only pure python libraries will work. You can download the wheel file for the library online and just upload to s3 and specify that for the python library path

Comment: that made the trick. Thanks. However, I'd need to use sftp for the project and Paramiko, which is the most know library in python for this is using C code for arithmetics. Is there any other library in pure python for sftp? or would then I have to create an EMR to do the work?

Comment: Although the doc doesn’t specify it clearly, it might be worth a try to create a python shell glue job and importing paramiko there. The python shell glue job supports pandas which isn’t a pure python library and hopefully it may work with importing paramiko. Plus you can use pandas to do your wrk.

Comment: I see. Creating a job for the file checking in python and then running the ETL in pyspark

Comment: This would be an option.. You can always trigger the glue job based on some event that when you run your code that does the ftp actions.